# How do you test JSON in Firefox?

Tags: json, firefox

I have a webservice where a mobile app can hit it and pass in some JSON data (and get a response back).

But I'd like to test this without having to run the mobile app each time.

So using Firefox, how do I send a request with JSON in it to my webservice to simulate the mobile app? Is there a part of the Firefox developer tools that will let me do this, or perhaps an extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is a site to test JSON.
http://jsonlint.com/